# Read values from file to JTextField and increment by 1 to another JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentlistener, documentfilter

I am making a ui in which there are two JTextFields,i can read data from text file to 
JTextField1.But the data does not gets updated to JTextField2,unless i 
enter a digit in JTextField1.Please Guide

Here is my Code:

```
 public class Cc extends JFrame 
  {
   public Cc() 
{
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   getContentPane().add(panel);

  final JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
  panel.add(field); 

     try{
        InputStream ips=new FileInputStream("test.txt"); 
        InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
        String line;
        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            field.setText(line);
          }
        br.close(); 
    }       
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   final JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
   panel.add(field1);

   field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            updateLabel(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            updateLabel(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            updateLabel(e);
        }

        private void updateLabel(DocumentEvent e) {
     String text = field.getText();
                    String text1 = field1.getText();

                    if (!text.isEmpty()) {
                        int p = Integer.parseInt(text);
                        int i = (p + 1);
                        String s = String.valueOf(i);
                        field1.setText(s);
                    } else {
                        field1.setText(null);
                    }

                }
    });

   ((AbstractDocument) field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int off, String str, AttributeSet   attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);  // remove non-  digits
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int off, int len, String str, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            fb.replace(off, len, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);  // remove non-digits
        }
    });

}
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  Cc c = new Cc();
  c.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  c.pack();
  c.setVisible(true);
  }
 }
```

Comment: I'm sure that success with DocumentFilter only, have to set one Document (for mirroring) or both JTextFields,

Comment: Can u please @mKorbel give me a idea of how to solve it.

Comment: can u please help me with this problem @mKorbel

Answer (score 0):

1) Why are you declaring field1 as final?
2) Write SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(panel); after you setText to field1, this will refresh the UI to reflect the new text

Comment: `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(panel);` is for setting the `Look and Feel`, setting `custom UI`, nor, never for methods implemented in API

Comment: it works for me when I update a UI component programatically...like in this case field2 and then refresh the UI to reflect the changes

Comment: it works for me when I update a UI component programatically == setText(), you don't need to call something another

Answer (score 0):

Try panel.repaint() after field1.setText()